# Google Visualization Query: Syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization, googlevis

For a webpage I created, I am querying a webpage using Google Visualization Query. However, it throws an error:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error: File: format+en,default+en,ui+en,table+en.I.js, Line: 26, Column: 315

It tells me where the error is occurring in Google's JavaScript file, but not in the queried webpage's code, which is causing the Google code to throw the error.

I have tried all sorts of code validations for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and they all say that the code is fine and I have looked over the code many times and can't seem to find it (although, I only have access to Notepad so that may be a problem).

So, I am hoping that someone here will see something that I'm not seeing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Untitled Spreadsheet</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=2.5,initial-scale=1,width=device-width">
    <link href="https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/css/736083944-waffle_k_ltr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            overflow: visible;
        }
        td, th {
            padding: 0;
        }
        table {
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
        #sheets-viewport {
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #sheets-viewport.widget-viewport {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .grid-container {
            overflow: visible;
            background: white;
        }
        .grid-table-container {
            overflow: visible;
        }
        #top-bar {
            background: url("//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/spreadsheets/publishheader.png") repeat-x bottom;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 0 0 5px;
        }
        #doc-title {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }
        #doc-title .name {
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        #sheet-menu {
            font-size: 13px;
            margin: 6px 0 0;
            padding: 0 0 5px;
        }
        #sheet-menu li {
            display: inline;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 8px;
        }
        #sheet-menu li.active {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }
        #top-bar #sheet-menu li.active {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }
        #sheet-menu a, #sheet-menu a:visited {
            color: #07c;
        }
        #footer {
            background: #f0f0f0;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            font-size: 13px;
            padding: 10px 10px;
        }
        .dash {
            padding: 0 6px;
        }
        .ritz .waffle a {
            color: inherit;
        }
        .ritz .waffle .s1 {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .ritz .waffle .s0 {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .ritz .waffle .s1, .ritz .waffle .s0 {
            color: #000000;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 10pt;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            white-space: nowrap;
            direction: ltr;
            padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var activeSheetId;

        function switchToSheet(id) {
            if (document.getElementById('sheet-menu')) {
                document.getElementById('sheet-button-' + activeSheetId).className = '';
                document.getElementById('sheet-button-' + id).className = 'active';
            }

            document.getElementById(activeSheetId).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
            activeSheetId = id;

            posObjs();
            return false;
        }

        function init() {
            var optPageSwitcher;

            function resize() {
                var optMobileWebHeader = document.getElementById('docs-ml-header-id');
                var optTopBar = document.getElementById('top-bar');
                var optFooter = document.getElementById('footer');
                var adjustedHeight = window.innerHeight - (optMobileWebHeader ? optMobileWebHeader.offsetHeight : 0) - (optTopBar ? optTopBar.offsetHeight : 0) - (optFooter ? optFooter.offsetHeight : 0);
                var adjustedWidth = window.innerWidth;
                var sheetsViewport = document.getElementById('sheets-viewport');
                sheetsViewport.style.width = (adjustedWidth + 'px');
                sheetsViewport.style.height = (adjustedHeight + 'px');
                if (optPageSwitcher) {
                    optPageSwitcher.resize(adjustedWidth, adjustedHeight);
                }
            }
            resize();
            window.onresize = resize;
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        _docs_flag_initialData = {
            "docs-sup": "/spreadsheets",
                "drive_url": "//drive.google.com?authuser\u003d0\u0026usp\u003dsheets_web",
                "docs-smheo": false,
                "info_params": {
                "token": "AC4w5VjCTRZY_Je4B-QO8ImKIS58FlGIhQ:1435710334787"
            },
                "ilcm": {
                "eui": "ADFN-csvCSVxiiNOkfyJkNXRm0VR4pDRyDdqLEBey8SfhQKFWKnFAxdpFj8DMnly9TIJvtMhkfl-",
                    "je": 1,
                    "sstu": 1435710334803000,
                    "si": "CLi4huTVuMYCFURKNwodvsMLPQ"
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <div id="top-bar">
        <div id="doc-title">    <span class="name">Untitled spreadsheet : Sheet1</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sheets-viewport" style="width: 1422px; height: 370px;">
        <div id="0" style="position: relative;" dir="ltr">
            <div class="ritz grid-container" dir="ltr">
                <table class="waffle">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="row-header freezebar-origin-ltr header-shim row-header-shim"></th>
                            <th class="header-shim" id="0C0" style="width: 100px;"></th>
                            <th class="header-shim" id="0C1" style="width: 100px;"></th>
                            <th class="header-shim" id="0C2" style="width: 100px;"></th>
                            <th class="header-shim" id="0C3" style="width: 100px;"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="height: 20px;">
                            <th class="row-headers-background row-header-shim" id="0R0" style="height: 20px;">
                                <div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px;">1</div>
                            </th>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">a</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">i</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">q</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">x</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 20px;">
                            <th class="row-headers-background row-header-shim" id="0R1" style="height: 20px;">
                                <div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px;">2</div>
                            </th>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">b</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">j</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">r</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">y</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 20px;">
                            <th class="row-headers-background row-header-shim" id="0R2" style="height: 20px;">
                                <div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px;">3</div>
                            </th>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">c</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">k</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">s</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">z</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 20px;">
                            <th class="row-headers-background row-header-shim" id="0R3" style="height: 20px;">
                                <div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px;">4</div>
                            </th>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">d</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">l</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">t</td>
                            <td class="s1" dir="ltr">1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 20px;">
                            <th class="row-headers-background row-header-shim" id="0R4" style="height: 20px;">
                                <div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px;">5</div>
                            </th>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">e</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">m</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">u</td>
                            <td class="s1" dir="ltr">2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 20px;">
                            <th class="row-headers-background row-header-shim" id="0R5" style="height: 20px;">
                                <div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px;">6</div>
                            </th>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">f</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">n</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">v</td>
                            <td class="s1" dir="ltr">3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 20px;">
                            <th class="row-headers-background row-header-shim" id="0R6" style="height: 20px;">
                                <div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px;">7</div>
                            </th>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">g</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">o</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">w</td>
                            <td class="s1" dir="ltr">4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 20px;">
                            <th class="row-headers-background row-header-shim" id="0R7" style="height: 20px;">
                                <div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px;">8</div>
                            </th>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">h</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">p</td>
                            <td class="s0" dir="ltr">x</td>
                            <td class="s1" dir="ltr">5</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">   <span>
            Published by
            <a title="Learn more about Google Sheets" href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/?authuser=0&amp;usp=sheets_web" target="_blank">Google Sheets</a>
        </span>
<span class="dash">-</span>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/abuse?id=1CrLw83xkUvISKTwE-etZkwUvLc_To_97af-0Sqr6RKQ">Report Abuse</a>
<span class="dash">-</span>
<span>Updated automatically every 5 minutes</span>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function posObj(sheet, id, row, col, x, y) {
            var rt1 = false;
            var sheetElement = document.getElementById(sheet);
            if (!sheetElement) {
                sheetElement = document.getElementById(sheet + '-grid-container');
            }
            if (sheetElement) {
                rt1 = sheetElement.getAttribute('dir') == 'rt1';
            }
            var r = document.getElementById(sheet + 'R' + row);
            var c = document.getElementById(sheet + 'C' + col);
            if (r && c) {
                var objElement = document.getElementById(id);
                var s = objElement.style;
                var t = y;
                while (r) {
                    t += r.offsetTop;
                    r = r.offsetParent;
                }
                var offsetX = x;
                while (c) {
                    offsetX += c.offsetLeft;
                    c = c.offsetParent;
                }
                if (rt1) {
                    offsetX -= objElement.offsetWidth;
                }
                s.left = offsetX + 'px';
                s.top = t + 'px';
                s.display = 'block';
                s.border = '1px solid #000000';
            }
        }

        function posObjs() {}
        posObjs();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        activeSheetId = '0';
        switchToSheet('0');
    </script>
</body>
```

EDIT:
This is the code of the webpage that sends a query to the code shown above. I know this code works because I have used it before.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {
            packages: ["table"]
        });

        function initialize() {
            var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://localhost/QueryGoogle.html');
            var string = prompt('Enter query:');
            if (string) {
                query.setQuery(string);
                query.send(queryResponse);
            }
        }

        function queryResponse(response) {
            if (response.isError()) {
                alert(response.getMessage() + response.getDetailedMessage());
                return;
            }
            var data = response.getDataTable();
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
            table.draw(data);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id='query' onclick='initialize()'>Enter Query</button>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
</body>
```

The `<html>` tags are cut off, but they are there.

Comment: Where is the reference to `google-visualization`?  I only see google docs api.

Comment: That is on the other webpage I made that queries this one. I didn't add it because I know it works because it worked for another webpage before.

Comment: I've been working with the Google Charts API for over a year, on my own projects and supporting others.  I have never seen a use case like you describe where a web page is used as a data source.  If I misunderstand you can set me straight, but please provide a little more detail about what you mean by a page querying this one.

Comment: I edited it with the other webpage's code. I'm not sure if it may be the problem, but I read somewhere that Google's query parses through HTML code and I also looked at the source code of a published Google Spreadsheet, and have tried to replicate it. But it may just be impossible because Google may have other things running in the background.